# git filter-branch error: "fatal: Not a valid object name HEAD"

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I am trying to use the git filter-branch command to move two sub-folders into a repository of its own. I tried to run the command below and resulted in a fatal error

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --subdirectory-filter "adb-*" -- master
```

Error:

```
Rewrite 52d9bf5425d940f730ccdad1548b7d957936cd00 (59/59) (55 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)
Ref 'refs/heads/master' was deleted
fatal: Not a valid object name HEAD
```

Can someone tell me what I might be missing?

Comment: Apparently there was no file named `abd-*`. I imagine you expected this to match, e.g., `abd-foo` and `abd-bar`, but `--subdirectory-filter` isn't capable of that.

Comment: @torek - Thanks. Is there a way to include multiple sub-folders?

Comment: Not with `--subdirectory-filter`, no. You can do it with some other filter instead (this will be slower but with just 55 commits to copy, you might not care about that).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to include multiple sub-folders

You can use `bfg-repo-cleaner`: https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ instead.

For example:

```
# Delete all files named 'id_rsa' or 'id_dsa' :
$ bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
```

I'm using it occasionally but dit tried it on folders.
Whenever I need to remove folders I'm using the `git subtree split` which is not the optimized solution but does the work.